# See debug messages from Chrome Extension's background page in Electron app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, electron

New to Electron here. I have added a Chrome extension to an Electron app successfully, but have hard time debugging it and specifically its background page. I know how to open a dummy html page for a background script in the browser, but is the same functionality possible here?

If not, is there any other convenient way of debugging the background script?

Thanks

Comment: Try using --inspect switch ([docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process)) then click "Open dedicated DevTools for Node" in chrome://inspect.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, @wOxxOm, however, the extension's background page is still not shown there - I only get Electron Main Context. Also, in Source, Content scripts is empty and in Network, I cannot find the extension folder at all.

Answer (score 1):

I just use [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) to console something in inspectedWindow's console panel, like this:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(activeId, {
    code: 'console.log("reconnect")'
}, function() {});
```

hope this helps！